# Programming PIC 18F4550 using Bootloader

Tags: pic, uart, bootloader

I was looking for simple boot loader which can program my PIC 18F4550 using uart communication. What I saw in all serial port boot loader program is, they are changing configuration bits especially LVP.  Is it necessary to set

```
  LVP=OFF (Turn off Low Voltage Programming)
```

in order to program flash using boot loader ??

Thanks I advance.

**Update- Add Config Bits used by Boot Loader**

Boot loader is used from this [site](http://www.etc.ugal.ro/cchiculita/software/picbootloader.htm)

```
; CONFIG1H
CONFIG  FOSC = INTOSC_HS      ; Oscillator Selection bits (Internal oscillator, HS oscillator used by USB (INTHS))
CONFIG  FCMEN = OFF           ; Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
CONFIG  IESO = OFF            ; Internal/External Oscillator Switchover bit (Oscillator Switchover mode disabled)

; CONFIG2L
CONFIG  PWRT = OFF            ; Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
CONFIG  BOR = OFF             ; Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset disabled in hardware and software)
CONFIG  BORV = 3              ; Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (Minimum setting 2.05V)
CONFIG  VREGEN = OFF          ; USB Voltage Regulator Enable bit (USB voltage regulator disabled)

; CONFIG2H
CONFIG  WDT = OFF             ; Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled (control is placed on the SWDTEN bit))
CONFIG  WDTPS = 1             ; Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:1)

; CONFIG3H
CONFIG  CCP2MX = ON           ; CCP2 MUX bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RC1)
CONFIG  PBADEN = OFF          ; PORTB A/D Enable bit (PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as digital I/O on Reset)
CONFIG  LPT1OSC = OFF         ; Low-Power Timer 1 Oscillator Enable bit (Timer1 configured for higher power operation)
CONFIG  MCLRE = ON            ; MCLR Pin Enable bit (MCLR pin enabled; RE3 input pin disabled)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never got boot loader program working even worse existing pic_pgm programmer stopped working after flashing above mentioned bootloader.

As I suspect boot loader might have changed PIC configuration bits which affected working of LVP programmer pic_pgm.

I flashed PIC18f4550 with PICKit3 programmer with following configuration settings and now LVP is working fine.

```
// CONFIG1L
#pragma config PLLDIV = 1       // PLL Prescaler Selection bits (No prescale (4 MHz oscillator input drives PLL directly))
#pragma config CPUDIV = OSC1_PLL2// System Clock Postscaler Selection bits ([Primary Oscillator Src: /1][96 MHz PLL Src: /2])
#pragma config USBDIV = 1       // USB Clock Selection bit (used in Full-Speed USB mode only; UCFG:FSEN = 1) (USB clock source comes directly from the primary oscillator block with no postscale)

// CONFIG1H
#pragma config FOSC = EC_EC     // Oscillator Selection bits (EC oscillator, CLKO function on RA6 (EC))
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Oscillator Switchover bit (Oscillator Switchover mode disabled)

// CONFIG2L
#pragma config PWRT = OFF       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOR = ON         // Brown-out Reset Enable bits (Brown-out Reset enabled in hardware only (SBOREN is disabled))
#pragma config BORV = 3         // Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (Minimum setting 2.05V)
#pragma config VREGEN = OFF     // USB Voltage Regulator Enable bit (USB voltage regulator disabled)

// CONFIG2H
#pragma config WDT = ON         // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT enabled)
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768    // Watchdog Timer Postscale Select bits (1:32768)

// CONFIG3H
#pragma config CCP2MX = ON      // CCP2 MUX bit (CCP2 input/output is multiplexed with RC1)
#pragma config PBADEN = ON      // PORTB A/D Enable bit (PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as analog input channels on Reset)
#pragma config LPT1OSC = OFF    // Low-Power Timer 1 Oscillator Enable bit (Timer1 configured for higher power operation)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Enable bit (MCLR pin enabled; RE3 input pin disabled)

// CONFIG4L
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Full/Underflow Reset Enable bit (Stack full/underflow will cause Reset)
#pragma config LVP = ON         // Single-Supply ICSP Enable bit (Single-Supply ICSP enabled)
#pragma config ICPRT = OFF      // Dedicated In-Circuit Debug/Programming Port (ICPORT) Enable bit (ICPORT disabled)
#pragma config XINST = OFF      // Extended Instruction Set Enable bit (Instruction set extension and Indexed Addressing mode disabled (Legacy mode))

// CONFIG5L
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP1 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP2 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CP3 = OFF        // Code Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not code-protected)

// CONFIG5H
#pragma config CPB = OFF        // Boot Block Code Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not code-protected)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not code-protected)

// CONFIG6L
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF       // Write Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not write-protected)

// CONFIG6H
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       // Configuration Register Write Protection bit (Configuration registers (300000-3000FFh) are not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       // Boot Block Write Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not write-protected)
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       // Data EEPROM Write Protection bit (Data EEPROM is not write-protected)

// CONFIG7L
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 0 (000800-001FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 1 (002000-003FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 2 (004000-005FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF      // Table Read Protection bit (Block 3 (006000-007FFFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// CONFIG7H
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF      // Boot Block Table Read Protection bit (Boot block (000000-0007FFh) is not protected from table reads executed in other blocks)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>
```

Learnings: Never ever change configuration registers if you don't understand it. Always refer to data sheet.

Answer (score 1):

The setting of that configuration bit must match your hardware (when you use that pin of portb as GPIO, LVP must be off, when you want to program using LVp it must be on, and that pin must be low to run the application).

Thye settiing of that bit has nothing to do with the bootloader, but because the bootloader is the "application" that is programmed using the normal programming means, the LVP setting must be set in the bootloader.

Summary: the LVP setting must be present in the bootloader, but it is (in nearly all cases) totally independent of the bootloader, so you can change it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Is it possible to set LVP = ON using LVP again if suppose currently LVP = OFF Or we need other methods like high voltage programming or ICSP ?

Comment: Once you havce set LVP = off LVP is deabled, hence you need other means (HVP) to re-enable LVP. IIRC you can't disable LVP using LVP.

Comment: I programmed PIC 18f4550 using [link] (http://picpgm.picprojects.net/install_raspberry_pi.html). The boot loader I programmed is not responding to host using uart. Now LVP programmer is also not detecting my pic. I have updated the question with used  config bits in boot loader. Is it due to config bits pic is not detected by LVP programmer?

Comment: Can I program my PIC again with above state LVP programmer? I don't have any other way to program it.